# Laravel 5.4 : Cannot connect to database on online server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pdo

I have just uploaded a Laravel project to a web server but it cannot be connected to the database. I have imported the database to phpmyadmin, and have also set the `.env` and `config/database.php` file. When I run the page, it still shows me my localhost database settings (username, password, database etc).

This is my .env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:qvuzPrZW3awGcn8etObsyAT7SaKRfgr6AHfpnUPfygE=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://findajob.af/

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database_name_on_server
DB_USERNAME=username_on_server
DB_PASSWORD=password_on_server
```

This is my config/database.php file

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database_name_on_server'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'username_on_server'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password_on_server'),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

When I load the page, it gives me following errors:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: )
```

And the second error message is

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 68:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

    1. in Connector.php line 68
    2. at PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=databasename_on_localhost', 'localhost_username', 'localhost_password', array(0, 2, 0, false, false)) in Connector.php line 68
```

Comment: Database and project are on the same server?

Comment: Yes they are on the same server. I purchased the hosting from easyname.com

Comment: So you don't need use that host - e73573-mysql.services.easyname.eu.
Try change it to localhost.

Comment: I did change it to localhost but still doesn't work. If you see the second error message, it is showing me the database name, username and password which I set on my localhost. I don't know why.

Comment: sometimes `127.0.0.1` works better than localhost, altough they should be the same thing.

Comment: Ok, I think where is the problem. Try clear your cache on the server.
`php artisan key:generate / php artisan cache:clear / php artisan config:clear` in Project directory.

Comment: U mean clear cache on localhost or online server? Can I do on online server?? I mean in Cpanel. I don't see any such option.

Comment: I mean online server. You need to connect with your server via ssh and run that 3 commands in project directory.

Comment: I am new to these things. I have enabled the SSH on my Cpanel but now I don't know how to run those commands and where? I am using Windows OS and the server is I think Linux

Comment: You can use `puTTy` to connect with your server via ssh. You only need to configure your server connection in putty. Read this [Tutorial](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404604/using-ssh-in-putty-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try this :

```
DB_HOST=hostname_from_server
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database_name_on_server
DB_USERNAME=username_on_server
DB_PASSWORD=password_on_server
```

After clear the cache on live like:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Hope this work for you !!!