# Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (2002) SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `rents`)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to connect a Laravel project to an existing database.

I have followed the [Eloquent Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions); however, I am still hitting the following error:

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (2002) SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
>   No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `rents`)

Here is my code:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'RentsController@index'
    ]);
```

**RentsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Rent;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class RentsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {   
        $rents = Rent::all();
        return view('welcome', ['rents' => $rents]);
    }

    ...
}
```

**Rent.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Rent extends Model {
    protected $table = 'rents';
}
```

**welcome.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($rents as $rent)
                <li>{{ $rent->title }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

*** One thing that may be the problem is that I am running the page locally (php artisan serve), while the database is real and online. Would that cause the issue? If so, any idea how to fix that? ***

Any idea what could be the problem? I have the .env file setup correctly, as it works on another page. However, on this one, it does not seem to be able to find the 'rents' table.

Thanks!!

Comment: does the database table `rents` exist? have you been able to connect to any other db tables?

Comment: might want to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory?rq=1

Comment: good question and thanks for your fast reply. Yes, the table "rents" does exist. No, unfortunately, I haven't been able to connect to any of the other tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDOException SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2002\] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Thanks @IzzEps, I've already taken a look at that page as well. Unfortunately, none of the advice could help. I guess one thing that is unique here is that I'm trying to connect to an already existing database, as opposed to creating it through Laravel itself. In this case, I don't need any migrations.

Comment: is ur .env file configured with the correct database conncetion parameters? 
- driver, host, port, database, username and password etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everyone, thank you for your help!

I figured it out. The problem was the DB_HOST.

I am running the page locally (i.e. php artisan serve) and the database is online. I do not have access to the database on my local computer. This is why it couldn't connect.

So, instead of DB_HOST = localhost OR 127.0.0.1, I put it to the actual host.

For example:

```
DB_HOST=hostname_from_server
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database_name_on_server
DB_USERNAME=username_on_server
DB_PASSWORD=password_on_server
```

Then, I needed to clear the cache in the terminal:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

Props to @[AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382938/laravel-5-4-cannot-connect-to-database-on-online-server) for the help!